# Access (VBA) - Append Records Not Already In Table

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have append Queries A, B to Table C. I am creating a report based off C, but I need the distinct rows. Now I could select the distinct rows from C, but I want to delete them as I go (ie so Table C does not contain 1,000,000,000+ records over time for each append), so the report has ALL the unique records from C, past, present, future until the end user deletes them.

My question is simply this. Is there any way to append only distinct (not append distinct, rather append to the table distinct) rows to Table C?
If not directly possible, VBA?

Comment: Add a primary key, or a composite key to enforce unique values.

Comment: Good suggestion, but I have no columns to throw it on. It is a master file, so there are only a small, small fraction but still existent nulls in each column.

Comment: Just build distinct queries for what you want to append: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp

Comment: Can you add a unique constraint on several fields? E.g. Field A,B,C must be present together to be unique.

Comment: @Absinthe But see, select Distinct does not delete the rows from Table C. And then I would have to save that query data somewhere, creating more hassle.

Comment: @RyanWildry. Unforunately not

Comment: @FamousFrik - That's the way Access works, you can't put everything you want to do in one SQL statement (well, you could, but good luck with that). You don't save the data in a table, you simply use the results of one query in another query.

Comment: Thanks for yall's help, you are correct. I'll work on the data itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use constraints to enforce this behavior, in this case a (composite) primary key: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-or-change-a-table-s-primary-key-in-Access-07b4a84b-0063-4d56-8b00-65f2975e4379

This will make sure, that you can't insert duplicate values into your table, which means that you won't have to delete the duplicates later on.

Define the primary key over all the columns that make a dataset unique.

Before adding a pk or constraint make sure to clean up your data though in order to remove all duplicate rows. The easiest way would probably to create a new table and fill it by using a `SELECT DISTINCT ....` from your current table.

Comment: as Ryan suggested, but this is not possible. My one distinct column has a couple of nulls, but the data can legitimately contain that

Comment: @FamousFrik huh? You can have a `NULL` column as part of a natural key / unique constraint. At least, on SQL Server. If Access won't let you have that, then you need to get rid of the `NULL` values somehow. There's no magic way, Access can't *guess* what "unique" means if you don't tell it which columns make up the natural key. A Primary Key constraint works too, but not if you already have an autonumber PK column (which you *should*).

Comment: Also you'll need to clean your dupes *before* you create the constraint, otherwise Access won't let you create it.

Comment: Indeed, I should have included that in my answer (will edit). As for NULL as part of a unique constraint: This only works for newer versions of Access (iirc MS Access 2010 and onwards) and I would generally advise against it (as it kind of defeats the purpose of a unique constraint...), but yeah technically it might work.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using any of the three [NOT IN, NOT EXISTS, or LEFT JOIN...NULL](https://explainextended.com/2009/09/15/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-sql-server/) queries to append data not currently in that table. Below assumes a primary key, *ID*, is used for the *distinctness*.

```sql
INSERT INTO TableC (Column1, Column2, Column3)
SELECT a.Column1, a.Column2, a.Column3
FROM QueryA a
LEFT JOIN TableC c
ON a.ID = c.ID
WHERE c.ID IS NULL;


INSERT INTO TableC (Column1, Column2, Column3)
SELECT a.Column1, a.Column2, a.Column3
FROM QueryA a
WHERE NOT EXISTS
   (SELECT 1 FROM TableC c
    WHERE a.ID = c.ID);


INSERT INTO TableC (Column1, Column2, Column3)
SELECT a.Column1, a.Column2, a.Column3
FROM QueryA a
WHERE a.ID NOT IN
   (SELECT c.ID FROM TableC c);
```

Now, if no single column but multiple fields denote uniqueness, add to the `JOIN` or `WHERE` clauses:

```sql
...
FROM QueryA a
LEFT JOIN TableC c
ON a.Column1 = c.Column1 AND a.Column2 = c.Column2 AND a.Column3 = c.Column3
WHERE a.Column1 IS NULL OR a.Column2 IS NULL OR a.Column3 IS NULL;

...
WHERE NOT EXISTS
   (SELECT 1 FROM TableC c
    WHERE a.Column1 = c.Column1 AND a.Column2 = c.Column2 AND a.Column3 = c.Column3);

...
WHERE a.Column1 NOT IN
   (SELECT c.Column1 FROM TableC c)
AND a.Column2 NOT IN
   (SELECT c.Column2 FROM TableC c)
AND a.Column3 NOT IN
   (SELECT c.Column3 FROM TableC c);
```